# Displaying the JqueryUI dialog box at a given coordinates of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am devoloping a calendar web app using [fullcalendar](http://www.fullcalendar.io).I wanted to imitate the google calendar to display information about an event and a delete button when it is clicked.I tried doing this :

```
    element.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
              if(e.which == 1){
                var Xcord = e.clientX ;
                var Ycord = e.clientY ;
                var X = 'left+' + Xcord.toString() ;
                var Y = 'top+' + Ycord.toString() ;
                console.log(X) ;
                console.log(Y) ;
                var  start = moment(event.start)
                var  end = moment(event.end) 

                //The contents of the dialog box is the start time and end time ... 

                $('#Info').html(start.format('ddd') + " " + start.format('MMM DD') + " " + start.format('hh:mm a') + " - " + end.format('hh:mm a')).css( 'font' , '15px arial, sans-serif');

                console.log(X+' '+Y);
                //I expected the box to open at given coordinates but it is not doing so !!!
                $('#dialog').dialog({

                  position: { my: "center bottom", at: X+' '+Y }
                }); 
    //More code here ...
```

However the dialog box is not opening at the given co-ordianates.It always opens at a fixed position (slightly left of center ) on the screen whereas I want it to open just above the calendar event where the user has clicked.

Is there anything wrong with the approach?

Also is there a better method to do this. Since even if it works , if I scroll down the calendar, the dialog box will no longer be attached to the event even. It will fixed to the screen at the mentioned coordinates.

Here is the part of the html and css :

```
     <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"  style="display: none;">
            <p id = 'Info'></p>
           <button type="button" id = 'deleteEvent'> Delete</button>
    </div>
```

And the CSS :

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::before, .ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::after {
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 150px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 10px;
    }

    .ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::before {
        border-color: #aaa transparent transparent transparent;
        top: 2px;
    }

    .ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s::after {
        border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
        top: 1px;
    }

    .ui-dialog {
        overflow:visible;
    }

    .ui-dialog-title {
        display:none;
    }

    .ui-dialog-titlebar {
        background:transparent;
        border:none;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        right:0;
    }
```

Comment: Nice to know I'm not the only person using dialogs and fullcalendar like this :D, first let me make sure this is what you are trying to do: jquery dialog is in the middle of your screen and if you scroll down it stays in the middle? (this is how I did it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I do this using css, this lets you decide where the dialog is generated and will also leave it there when you scroll, first in your css add this class:
(make this however you want it, I use it so my dialog is always in the center of my screen)</strike>

```
.fixed-dialog{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Then when you create the dialog, in the modal options put this line:

```
$("#name").load().dialog(
                {   //Set options for the dialog here
                        dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog'
                });
```

EDIT: if I'm understanding correctly you want to do something like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", {
     at: "center bottom",
     of: this // this refers to the cliked element
   }).dialog('open');
```

Comment: if you don't want people opening up multiple dialogs stacked on top of eachother make sure to set modal:true in the dialog options

Comment: I think my question was a little ambigious :( . I want to display the dialog box   just above the event on which the user has clicked. It is not known beforehand...  So I tried  "position: { my: "center bottom", at: X+' '+Y }" where X and Y are calculated from the coordinates where the user has clicked. But this is not working !!!!

Comment: I've seen soemthing like that before, let me check if I can find it

Comment: It's like if the user clicked on a calendar event... say at (132 , 520) coordinates on the screen , then I want the dialog box to pop up at the same coordinates. Now if he closes it and clicks on another event at (230 , 730) , now the dialog box has to open at (230 , 730) .... This way ..

Comment: that's what that code does though... I tested it on my own calendar (the coordinates are not exactly the same but the dialog pops up somewhere else if I click on a different event) You just need to play around with the at: "center bottom" thing

Comment: Ohh !! .. I will check it again !! Huge thanks btw :)